# Unity Wallpaper with Openbox WM?

Tags: unity, desktop-background, openbox

I've installed Openbox, tint2 and synapse to replace Unity on my Ubuntu 12.04 installation. When I log into my account openbox starts with a grey background, as expected.

I just replaced Compiz as WM, I still boot into the login screen from Unity.

Sometimes, I don't know when exactly, the Unity background pops up.

What's the name of the wallpaper tool and how do I set up Openbox to show the wallpaper at start? (And how do I change the wallpaper?)

Comment: So you're running a pure Openbox session at the time of logging in or is it a Ubuntu (=Unity) session with Openbox instead of Compiz as the WM? Re. wallpapers, I've heard of [feh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/feh) but I can't say more. I don't use wallpapers.

Comment: Good point, I updated my question. I still use Unity session with Openbox as WM. The problem seems to be the Unity wallpaper app gets fired up some when. I would like to utilize it from the beginning or deinstall it. I know there's feh, but the Unity wallpaper thing isn't feh, or?

Comment: No idea at all about wallpapers or Unity :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a specific tool for the wallpaper. It's configurable but you have to use the gnome-session tool. If I use that, the whole compiz desktop starts. So i backed off and tried feh, which didn't work for me because I couldn't set a solid background color and additionally a centered image.

So I took [hsetroot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/hsetroot.1.html). Wasn't installed per default in 12.04 but it's in the repositories. Till now it works as expected and the Unity background didn't pop up as it did before.